# Using Flextable to Word for Free-Text Survey Responses

Tags: r, r-markdown, rendering, flextable

I am doing some survey analysis and am stumped with a weird issue.

When I try to write out a `flextable` object to Word, I'm getting a blank document of ~30 pages. This has previously worked in R and R Markdown without any issues, and I can't figure out why it's happening.

Here is the dput:

```
df <- structure(list(Response = c("Comment from patron 1", "Comment from customer 2", 
"Comment from someone 3", "Comment from nobody 4", "Comment from patron 5", 
"Comment from customer 6", "Comment from someone 7", "Comment from nobody 8"
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Here's the code I'm using to write to a directory that I am 100% sure I have access to:

```
ft <- as.data.frame(df)
ft <- flextable(ft)
ft <- theme_zebra(ft)
ft <- autofit(ft)

doc <- read_docx()
doc <- body_add_flextable(doc, value = ft)
print(doc, target = "Doc2.docx")
```

Any ideas to help resolve or troubleshoot this? Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Hi, pretty sure it is related to https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/145. Workaround: add a reasonable fix widtth on the column that goes with huge width. Note I think you are on Windows as it does not occur on other system.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidGohel. This solved the issue. Also, thanks for everything you do to maintain `flextable` - it's an amazing package!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by David Gohel, adding a width argument solved the issue:

```
ft <- as.data.frame(df)
ft <- flextable(ft)
ft <- theme_zebra(ft)
ft <- autofit(ft)
**ft <- width(ft, width = 7)**

doc <- read_docx()
doc <- body_add_flextable(doc, value = ft)
print(doc, target = "Doc2.docx")
```